# Use the default merge tool with git and Mac OS X

Tags: macos, git

I was changing the default merge tool of git, and an error occurred with my configuration, now my git doesn't work.
Is possible come back to the default configuration?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what git commands are not working any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Alan Haggai Alavi's answers, which is inclusive of the following, if you are confident that changing the merge tool was the problem, you can just revert your merge tool changes:

```
git config --global --unset merge.tool
git config --unset merge.tool
```

Answer (score 1):

Review Git configuration files:

- Global user configuration file: `~/.gitconfig`
- Repository configuration file: `.git/config`